# Extract elements from a list of lists and assign that as a value in a pandas data frame column

Tags: list, python-2.7, pandas

I have a list of lists generated as follows:

```
input = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
siglist = sum([map(list, combinations(input, i)) for i in range(len(input) + 1)], [])

print siglist[25]
    ['d', 'g']
```

Now, I want to create a column "new"" in an existing dataframe df as follows

```
color   location    type    new
blue    TX          MATTE   [d,g]
black   NA          GLOSS   [d,g]
red     UT          MATTE   [d,g]
orange  UT          GLOSS   [d,g]
white   WA          MATTE   [d,g]
```

I was hoping that something like below would work;

```
df['new'] = (siglist[25])[:]
```

however, i get an error: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`
Could anyone please help, what am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `apply` to assign via `loc`

```
df.loc[:, 'new'] = df.apply(lambda x: (siglist[25])[:], axis=1)
```